# Grant Lake Formation read permission to all tables in a Glue database through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-lake-formation

I am working on defining a reader role in a data lake that uses Lake Formation for access control. I would like to grant this role `Select` permission to all the tables in relevant databases, so that it automatically picks up new tables that are created. In the [documentation of CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lakeformation-permissions-tableresource.html) I can see that this is currently marked as not supported, `TableWildcard`  looks like a solution that I would like to use.

I am currently looking at either hardcoding the table names that this role should have access to or writing a `boto3` script that would pick up all the tables in the database and adding the permissions to them through Lake Formation. This could be running with Lambda on a regular schedule, which would automate this process, but of course it will not be the prettiest approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to the current documentation, it is possible to use `"TableWildcard": {}` construct as shown in the example below to grant permissions to the role to all the tables in a given database.

```
"ExamplePermission": {
  "Type": "AWS::LakeFormation::Permissions",
  "Properties": {
    "DataLakePrincipal": {
      "DataLakePrincipalIdentifier": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "ExampleRole",
          "Arn"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Resource": {
      "TableResource": {
        "DatabaseName": "example_database",
        "TableWildcard": {}
      }
    },
    "Permissions": [
      "SELECT"
    ],
    "PermissionsWithGrantOption": []
  }
}
```

For anyone using CDK, here is a Python flavour of the table resource property:

```
import aws_cdk.aws_lakeformation as lakeformation

table_property = lakeformation.CfnPermissions.TableResourceProperty(
    database_name="example_database",
    table_wildcard={}
)
```

Comment: Is there a wildcard for database? i.e. All database, all tables

Comment: I'm not getting this to work.. My AWS::LakeFormation::Permissions Resource looks identical to yours but CloudFormation is telling me that "Resource does not exist or requester is not authorized to access requested permissions". I can create permissions explicitly for any named Table under this Database using CFN though.. Don't get it, any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all the tables in your relevant databases, why don't you use the [DataBaseResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lakeformation-permissions-databaseresource.html)? This is what I am using and it works like a charm.

Comment: I do, the role is created with a database Super permissions. But when I run the Athena query, it fils with insufficient Lake Formation permissions. After adding Select permission through the `TableResource`, Athena query is executing successfully.

Comment: Did you register the underlying data location (S3) as well?

Comment: I have just experimented with registering the data location and it didn't help. When I switch to the role I am defining in Athena I simply don't see any tables, which is an indication of the missing permissions.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use lf-tags.

Assign all databases, the same lf-tag (tables in the database will inherit the lf-tags).
Grant permissions to the users for the lf-tag.